# How to get Maximum and minimum values of a one of the columns of a tableview

Tags: javafx-8

I have a Tableview with some columns, how can I retrieve the maximum number from one the columns to a textfield and the lowest number of the same column to another textfield

Comment: Just go through the items list and compare the value of the property used in the column...

Comment: Thanks for ur response but pls can u give me an example (code included)